# Advice on the feasibility for environment management

Tags: architecture, environment-variables, dependency-management, software-design, iaas

I've come across a bunch of topics but didn't find anything that hits my issue. Indeed, just looking for an opinion of the feasibility for a problem-solving potential solution - or either a smarter solution :)

I'm figuring out ways to standardize my development environment, given we usually code in different computers sometimes. I wondered if, beyond the usual ways, would be feasible to create a web application where the features, engine and anything else (likely Google Colab, C/C++ on-line compilers etc).

As it would deal with the whole machine assets (excluding graphical), I'm not that sure if I'm too over in this trade-off or even for a personal project it would be feasible to do so.

Sorry if this is a dumb question - I'm a scientist/engineer, and, unfortunately, not an IT professional. :/

I've tried for contents in text books, Discord, GitHub, papers but as my demand is for an advice, without interaction I think that's why I didn't find what I'm looking for. I'm expecting just an advice/opinion.